# NameError when calling a class method

Tags: python, class, methods, attributes, nameerror

trying to understand classes and methods in Python 3.7. I keep running the code below, but keep getting this NameError, associated with the points variable I established in the initialize method of the Stats class. I believe the error is the result of some problem recognizing local/global variables, but can't put my finger on it. Does anyone have any ideas?

```py
class Stats:
    def __init__(self, points, rebounds, assists, steals):
        self.points = points
        self.rebounds = rebounds
        self.assists = assists
        self.steals = steals

    def tripDub(self):
        if points >= 10 and rebounds >= 10 and assists >= 10 and steals >= 10:
            return "Yes!"
        else:
            return "Nope!"

s = Stats(30, 20, 9, 5)
print("Did he earn a Triple Double? Result:", s.tripDub())
```

Comment: In the tripDub() method you need to refer to class variables using self. e.g. `if self.points >= 10 and self.rebounds >= 10 and self.assists >= 10 and self.steals >= 10:`

Comment: If any of the answers solved your question, it's good practice to upvote them and accept the best one. The latter also grants you a small rep bonus :)

Comment: Think carefully about the logic. Where the code says `self.points = points`, why does it not simply say `points=points`? What does the `self.` part mean? Do you see how this applies to the `tripDub` method as well?

Answer (score 4):

You need `self.` before referencing instance variables:

```
class Stats:
    def __init__(self, points, rebounds, assists, steals):
        self.points = points
        self.rebounds = rebounds
        self.assists = assists
        self.steals = steals

    def tripDub(self):
        if self.points >= 10 and self.rebounds >= 10 and self.assists >= 10 and self.steals >= 10:
            return "Yes!"
        else:
            return "Nope!"


s = Stats(30, 20, 9, 5)
print("Did he earn a Triple Double? Result:", s.tripDub())
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to reference `points`, `rebounds`, `assists` and `steals` using self in the `tripDub` function.

Example: `self.points`